# What is the difference between chromemediasource - 'desktop', 'window', 'screen'?

Tags: javascript, electron, navigator, screen-recording

What is the difference between `chromemediasource` (`desktop`, `window`, `screen`) in `Navigator.getUserMedia()` ?